# Combine multiple regex expressions in pandas.DataFrame.str.replace?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I've got a column in dataframe I want to clean up by removing the brackets.

```
1                          Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
2                 Florence (University of North Alabama)
3        Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
4             Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
5               Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
6                              Troy (Troy University)[2]
7      Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...
8                      Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
10         Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
12            Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
```

I used `unitowns['City'].str.replace('\(.*\)','').str.replace('\[.*\]','')` to get the intended result as follows-

```
1                            Auburn 
2                          Florence 
3                      Jacksonville 
4                        Livingston 
5                        Montevallo 
6                              Troy 
7                        Tuscaloosa 
8                          Tuskegee 
10                        Fairbanks 
12                        Flagstaff
```

Is there a way to combine these expressions? This code does not seem to work -> `unitowns['City'].str.replace('(\(.*\)) | (\[.*\])','')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.extract`/`str.findall`
Rather than removing irrelevant content, why not extract the relevant ones instead?

```
df.City.str.extract(r'(.*?)(?=\()', expand=False)
```

Or,

```
df.City.str.findall(r'(.*?)(?=\()').str[0]
```

```
0          Auburn 
1        Florence 
2    Jacksonville 
3      Livingston 
4      Montevallo 
5            Troy 
6      Tuscaloosa 
7        Tuskegee 
8       Fairbanks 
9       Flagstaff 
Name: City, dtype: object
```

You may also want to get rid of leading/trailing spaces post extraction. You can call `str.strip` on the result -

```
df.City = df.City.str.extract(r'(.*?)(?=\()', expand=False).str.strip()
```

Or,

```
df.City = df.City.str.findall(r'(.*?)(?=\()').str[0].str.strip()
```

**Regex Details**

```
(      # capture group
.*?    # non-greedy matcher
)
(?=    # lookahead
\(     # opening parenthesis
)
```

---

**Option 2**
`str.split`
If your city names only consist of one word, `str.split` would also work.

```
df.City.str.split('\s', 1).str[0]

0          Auburn
1        Florence
2    Jacksonville
3      Livingston
4      Montevallo
5            Troy
6      Tuscaloosa
7        Tuskegee
8       Fairbanks
9       Flagstaff
Name: City, dtype: object
```

---

**Option 3**
`str.replace`
Condensing your chained calls, you can use -

```
df['City'].str.replace(r'\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]', '').str.strip()

0          Auburn
1        Florence
2    Jacksonville
3      Livingston
4      Montevallo
5            Troy
6      Tuscaloosa
7        Tuskegee
8       Fairbanks
9       Flagstaff
Name: City, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This helps. Although, the reason I want to combine regex is I've got some data that are multiple words with numbers at the beginning and brackets in the middle. Would be easier to format what to remove!

Comment: @COLDSPEED Awesome! The non-greedy matcher was the key then!! Thanks.
P.S- I ended up using the extract for this one! Thanks for a lot!!